# Matlab how to compare matrices and take max

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Hi i have this equation in mathematics:

```
 φ= max(a,-r)
```

where `a,r` are matrices with the same dimensions.

How can i take the result of this in Matlab.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think just

```
phi = max(a,-r);
```

would do.

Comment: @Divakar, Actually I didn't know `max` would do that. I just find out!

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1:** Using logical indexing -

```
φ = a.*(a>(-r)) + (-r).*~(a>(-r))
```

**Approach #2:** Creating an array of dimension one grater than `a` and `r` and using `max` along the highest dimension of the resultant array -

```
φ = max(cat(ndims(a)+1,a,-r),[],ndims(a)+1)
```

Using `approach #2` would make more sense when you have a series of inputs among which the `max` is to be found out, i.e. for a case like `max(a,r1,r2,r3..)`.